# Comparing values with zero

Tags: java

How to compare floating point values with zero, I may get integers like **0,1,2** or floating point numbers **0.0 ,41.2** etc.  How to compare these values against 0

I tried this way

```
  String x="<some value either 0 or 1.2"

  If(Integer.parseInt(x)==0)
  System.out.println("parsed");
```

with input `0` it is working, with `1.2` throwing format exception.

Regards,

Raj

Comment: You cannot represent a real number like `1.2` as an integer.

Comment: That is, when calling `parseInt()` with a string that doesn't represent an integer, you get that error. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your values can be decimal numbers, use this for parsing the string:

```
Double.parseDouble(x)
```

The comparison remains the same, though:

```
if (Double.parseDouble(x) == 0)
```

Comment: if (double.parseDouble(x) == 0)

Comment: it fails if incoming string has "0" becuase when you do double.parseDouble(0) it became 0.0

Comment: @raj no it doesn't. `0` is equal to `0.0`